# is there another way I can fire my js function instead of using .change

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, checkbox, onchange

I have this function which calls some other functions when a checkbox is checked/unchecked:

```
 $page = $(event.target);

 $page.find(".checkboxes").change(function () {
     if (this.checked) {
        checked(this);
     } else {
        unchecked();
    }
 });
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in IE 8 (internet explorer 8 seems to call my checked/unchecked functions twice). Is there another event I can call for a checkbox that would fire this stuff off better?

Comment: Since `$page` is `$(event.target)` I suppose that the whole code you've shown is inside another event listener, right? If that's the case, you'll be binding the onchange handler multiple times, and that can cause the behavior you describe. Move the part that does `$page.find(".checkboxes").change` outside the other event handler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    .focus(function(){})
```

or you use

```
    .click(function(){})
```

Comment: I think "click" is the best, since you can tab to a checkbox.